# Spring Boot : Values of all attributes of DTO are null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm developing a Spring Boot application and I have a problem with my POST request. When I do the request it seems that every field in the request body is null.

Client entity

```java
    package com.tradeManagementApp.tradeManagement.model;
    
    import lombok.*;
    
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.util.List;
    
    @Data
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
    @Table(name ="Client")
    @Entity
    public class Client extends AdstractEntity{
    
        @Column(name = "nom")
        private String nom;
    
        @Column(name = "prenom")
        private String prenom;
    
        @Column(name = "photo")
        private String photo;
    
        @Embedded
        private Adresse adresse;
    
        @Column(name = "mail")
        private String mail;
    
        @Column(name = "tel")
        private String tel;
    
        @Column(name = "identreprise")
        private int idEntreprise;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
        private List<CommandeClient> commandeClients;
    }
```

Adress entity

```java
    package com.tradeManagementApp.tradeManagement.model;
    
    import lombok.*;
    
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Embeddable
    public class Adresse implements Serializable {
    
    
        @Column(name = "adresee1")
        private  String adresse1;
    
        @Column(name = "adresee2")
        private  String adresse2;
    
        @Column(name = "ville")
        private  String ville;
    
        @Column(name = "pays")
        private  String pays;
    
        @Column(name = "codepostal")
        private  String codepostal;
    }
```

Client DTO

```java
    
    @Builder
    @Data
    public class ClientDto {
    
        private Integer id;
        private String nom;
        private String prenom;
        private String photo;
        private AdresseDto adresse;
        private String mail;
        private Integer idEntreprise;
        private String tel;
        @JsonIgnore
        private List<CommandeClientDto> commandeClients;
    
        public static ClientDto fromEntity (Client client){
            if (client == null){
    
    //            todo throw an exception
                return null;
            }
    
            return ClientDto.builder()
                    .id(client.getId())
                    .nom(client.getNom())
                    .prenom(client.getPrenom())
                    .photo(client.getPhoto())
                    .adresse(AdresseDto.fromEntity(client.getAdresse()))
                    .mail(client.getMail())
                    .idEntreprise(client.getIdEntreprise())
                    .tel(client.getTel())
                    .build();
        }
    
        public static Client toEntity(ClientDto clientDto){
            if (clientDto == null){
    
    //            todo throw an exception
                return null;
            }
    
            Client client = new Client();
    
            client.setId(clientDto.getId());
            client.setNom(clientDto.getNom());
            client.setPrenom(clientDto.getPrenom());
            client.setPhoto(clientDto.getPhoto());
            client.setMail(clientDto.getMail());
            client.setTel(clientDto.getTel());
            client.setIdEntreprise(clientDto.getIdEntreprise());
            client.setAdresse(AdresseDto.toEntity(clientDto.getAdresse()));
    
            return client;
        }
    
    }
```

Adress DTO

```java
    
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    @Data
    public class AdresseDto {
    
        private  String adresse1;
        private  String adresse2;
        private  String ville;
        private  String pays;
        private  String codePostal;
    
        public static AdresseDto fromEntity(Adresse adresse){
            if (adresse == null){
    
    //            todo throw an exception
                return null;
            }
            return AdresseDto.builder()
                    .adresse1(adresse.getAdresse1())
                    .adresse2(adresse.getAdresse2())
                    .ville(adresse.getVille())
                    .pays(adresse.getPays())
                    .codePostal(adresse.getCodepostal())
                    .build();
        }
    
        public static Adresse toEntity (AdresseDto adresseDto){
            if (adresseDto == null){
    
    //            todo throw an exception
                return null;
            }
    
    
            Adresse adresse = new Adresse();
    
            adresse.setAdresse1(adresseDto.getAdresse1());
            adresse.setAdresse2(adresseDto.getAdresse2());
            adresse.setVille(adresseDto.getVille());
            adresse.setPays(adresseDto.getPays());
            adresse.setCodepostal(adresseDto.getCodePostal());
    
            return adresse;
        }
    }
```

client validator

```
    public class ClientValidator {
    
        public static List<String> validate (ClientDto clientDto){
            List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    
            if (clientDto == null){
                errors.add("veuillez renseignez le nom du client");
                errors.add("veuillez renseignez le prenom du client");
                errors.add("veuillez renseignez l'email du client");
                return errors;
            }
            if ( !StringUtils.hasLength(clientDto.getNom())){
                errors.add("veuillez renseignez le nom du client");
            }
            if ( !StringUtils.hasLength(clientDto.getPrenom())){
                errors.add("veuillez renseignez le prenom du client");
            }
            if ( !StringUtils.hasLength(clientDto.getMail())){
                errors.add("veuillez renseignez l'email du client");
            }
            if ( !StringUtils.hasLength(clientDto.getTel())){
                errors.add("veuillez renseignez le numero de telephone du client");
            }
    
            return errors;
        }
    }
```

Save client method in Service

```
    @Override
        public ClientDto save(ClientDto clientDto) {
            List<String> errors = ClientValidator.validate(clientDto);
    
            if (!errors.isEmpty()){
                log.error("Client is not Valid {}",clientDto);
                throw new InvalidEntityException("le client est invalide", ErrorCode.CLIENT_NOT_VALID, errors);
            }
            return ClientDto.fromEntity(
                    clientRepositry.save(ClientDto.toEntity(clientDto))
            );
        }
```

Client controller

```java
   
        @PostMapping(value = CLIENT_ENDPOIND+"/", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        @Operation(summary = "enregistrer un client", description = "cette methode permet de enregistrer un client"
        )
        @ApiResponses(value = {
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "client enregistrer avec succée"),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "les informations du clients ne sont pas valides")
        })
        ClientDto save(@RequestBody ClientDto clientDto);
```

When i do a post request using swagger UI

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8080/tradeManagement/v1/clients/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  
  "nom": "string",
  "prenom": "string",
  "photo": "string",
  "adresse": {
    "adresse1": "string",
    "adresse2": "string",
    "ville": "string",
    "pays": "string",
    "codePostal": "string"
  },
  "mail": "string",
  "idEntreprise": 0,
  "tel": "string"
}'
```

I have an error stating that the values of all attributes of customer Dto are null.

```
ERROR 13948 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.t.t.s.i.ClientServiceImplementation    : Client is not Valid ClientDto(id=null, nom=null, prenom=null, photo=null, adresse=null, mail=null, idEntreprise=null, tel=null, commandeClients=null)
```

response body

```
{
  "httpCode": 400,
  "errorCode": "CLIENT_NOT_VALID",
  "message": "le client est invalide",
  "errors": [
    "veuillez renseignez le nom du client",
    "veuillez renseignez le prenom du client",
    "veuillez renseignez l'email du client",
    "veuillez renseignez le numero de telephone du client"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What does ClientValidator.validate do ?

Comment: validate the present or not of attribute

Comment: Can you show us the errors list returned with the exception?

Comment: @mohamedchadad yes i added it in the topic

Comment: There's a lot of code here that doesn't seem related to the issue. Can you provide a [**minimal**, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I tried using just your `ClientDto` and a `PostMapping` endpoint, and it was working as expected.

Comment: @Knox I don't know where is the problem because all POST request that using the embedded attribute Adress don't work.

Comment: I think that jackson can't able to map a JSON to Entity. But i don't know how to tell it to serialize

Comment: @FranckTCHIENGUEN Please see the "Minimal" section of the link I sent- it describes how to produce an example even if you don't know where the problem is. If the problem is that all fields of `ClientDto` when it's a request body are null, then you should limit the scope to your controller, ideally with a `System.out.println()` showing the null, and the `ClientDto` itself. We don't need `Client`, `Adresse`, `ClientDto#fromEntity`, `ClientDto#toEntity`, and so on. Otherwise, we have to clean up all of that ourselves to get it to compile. And when I did, I wasn't seeing the same issue.

Comment: It would be easier if you give us something that we can both run and see the problem, otherwise we'll be on different pages (which is why I am already not able to reproduce the same error you are seeing).

Comment: try putting the url at the end of the curl command, I'm not sure it's going to work with the arguments after the url.

Comment: @Knox ok. I will do better next time. it's my first question on stack over flow

Comment: No need to apologize, and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 7):

You may have incorrect import in your controller:

Add:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
```

Remove:

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody;
```

Comment: Right. thank you very much